# How to make a richTextBox scroll?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im adding a lot of text to the richTextbox1 i have a scroll bar on the right but the text inside wich is lines that add all the time dosent scroll.
Only if i drag down with the mouse the bar on the right i see the text scroll.

I want to make it scroll automatic once the text inside is getting to the bottom of the richTextbox.

How can i do it ?

Comment: google gave me this: http://geekswithblogs.net/Waynerds/archive/2006/01/29/67506.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever text is added in the RichTextBox control you should get these statements executes to move the cursor at the end of text in the RichTextBox. Suppose the name of RichTextBox control is richTextBox, you would have statements as under.

```
richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 3):

**This code will work Perfectly :**  ------

```
namespace CustomRTB
{
    public class CustomRTB : RichTextBox
    {
        #region API Stuff
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

        private const int SB_HORZ = 0x0;
        private const int SB_VERT = 0x1;
        #endregion
        public int HorizontalPosition
        {
            get { return GetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_HORZ); }
            set { SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_HORZ, value, true); }
        }

        public int VerticalPosition
        {
            get { return GetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_VERT); }
            set { SetScrollPos((IntPtr)this.Handle, SB_VERT, value, true); }
        }
    }
}
```

you can check with **RichTextBox Class** Property it includes

public RichTextBoxScrollBars ScrollBars { get; set; }

This property enables you to provide horizontal and vertical scroll bars to the user of the RichTextBox control to enable scrolling .